# cxfreeze command not found in windows

Tags: python, configuration, compilation, cx-freeze

I installed [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) via the *msi installer* on my Windows 7 pc. It told me the installation was successful and running `pip install cx_Freeze` doesn't cause anything.

Anyway when I try to run the command `cxfreeze --version` in the windows command line it tells me, that the program can not be found. I'm not even sure, if this command has to be run in the command line, or in some python shell.

Despite successful installation, there is no executable `cxfreeze.xyz` file in my file system. But in the python installation folder there is a file `Scripts\cxfreeze`. This file has no extension and can't be executed in the command line. It's not a binary file, but contains the following text instead:

```
#!C:\Python\32-bit\3.4\python.exe

from cx_Freeze import main

main()
```

How can I make cxfreeze run, like stated in their documentation?

Comment: What are the contents of your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Python related content of my PATH: ``C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more research I found, that it's a known bug of cx_Freeze:
https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/90/cxfreeze-in-windows-is-not-executable

---

*In the link there is also a work around, which i quote here:*

I create a `cxfreeze.cmd` in `venv\Scripts\` with the following contents:

```
:: cxfreeze.cmd
:: make sure cxfreeze from the official installation is in the same folder
:: python is in my path
python "%~dp0\cxfreeze" %*
```

And cmd.exe recognizes `cxfreeze.cmd`, so that I can run `cxfreeze --version` now. Maybe the developers could consider adding my file into the official installation process.

Comment: An alternative workaround that worked for me can be found in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270885/installing-cx-freeze-to-python-at-windows/25936813#25936813) SO topic.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me:

Run in cmd:

`python [Python folder's dir]\Scripts\cxfreeze-postinstall`

(Solution thanks to [Puggie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1504026/puggie))