# pip cxfreeze is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: pip, cx-freeze

I don't know what the deal is, but I installed cx_Freeze with pip

```
pip install cx_Freeze
```

Pip says that everything is installed into my site-packages folder.

I double checked that cx_Freeze is in the folder and that the folder in on my windows PATH.

But whenever I try to run cxfreeze I get an `'cxfreeze' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` error.

I tried running:

```
cxfreeze bookit.py --target-dir bookitdir

cx_Freeze bookit.py --target-dir bookitdir
```

all to no avail. I am not super familiar with windows. I do all my hacking on my macbook, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Edit: I also confirmed that C:\Python27\Scripts\ is on the path as well. Still no dice.

Comment: Known issue: https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/90/cxfreeze-in-windows-is-not-executable I'll try to fix it today.

Comment: possible duplicate of [installing cx\_Freeze to python at windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270885/installing-cx-freeze-to-python-at-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but In Windows 11,
Assuming you've already had the environmental variables set up.

Using **Python 3.10**
After installing `cx_Freeze` with **pip** like this

```
pip install cx_Freeze
```

You have to call it like this

```
cxfreeze <your-python-file>
```

instead of the usual linux `cx_Freeze`

This is how windows copy the file, you have to reference it like below, or you could also change the name of the file to the one you normally use in Linux

[image]

Now you can enjoy playing [Sticky Bubble on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fadsel.stickybubble) and relax a bit while it installs and compiles your app :)

Answer (score 0):

If python was installed in "C:\Python34\", usually cxfreeze would be installed in "C:\Python34\Scripts". Make sure it was in PATH too.
And cxfreeze.bat should be edited to point to the right exe files.

Comment: could you elaborate on the part about editing the .bat? I have never had to do that for other machines. Usually, it's just 'pip install' and then it works..

Answer (score 0):

As the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270885/installing-cx-freeze-to-python-at-windows) just do the following orders:

1. cd to your python directory and then the Scripts folder, for me it is:

   ```
   C:\Python27\Scripts
   ```
2. Here just run the following command:

   ```
   python cxfreeze-postinstall
   ```
3. Now you can use cxfreeze like this:

   ```
   cxfreeze hello.py --target-dir=your_target_directory
   ```

**Hint:** For 3 **DO NOT** forget to run cmd as Administrator