# cxfreeze is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have installed cx_freeze 5.1.1 (https://pypi.org/project/cx_Freeze/) in a virtual environment. The installation went correctly and the file cxfreeze is in the folder ~myproject\scripts.

Yet when I try to run cx_freeze I get this error: 'cxfreeze' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I am using python 3.7, I managed to make it work using python 2.7

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25936813/8516269)?

Comment: I just did, it did create the .bat files, and I now get a weird error: 

'(Happybot) ~\virtualenvs\Project>cxfreeze setup.py
'~\virtualenvs\Project\python.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

To avoid using this command (cxfreeze), I built a setup.py, it executes the program, ann I now have an issue 'ImportError: No module named '__init__.py' ', but I suspect it is a python version issue

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including your main program script and your `setup.py`script?

Comment: Hi, I found the solution (well I think), fact is that my program name was ProjectV1.2.py, and when cx_freeze was looking for it to create the __init__.py file it was only looking for something named "ProjectV1". I just had to add some package to the setup.py file, and it is now alright. @jpeg still thanks for your help & time